# What is a web based vpn for Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, vpn

Does anyone know of a VPN that works through the web. Specifically, suppose that there are two computers such the only open port is 80 on each of them. Also, you can't open any other ports. How do you simulate an open port, such that it is like they are on the same local network with whatever open ports are wished. It should also (obviously) work with Ubuntu. The reason why I want this, is so that I could show my dad how to set up ssh at places he can't open ports.

Note: It shouldn't break port 80 for other purposes, such as web browsing. Preferably, it should just act like a normal web connection using normal web protocols, but use those  protocols to send information that would go over other ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find a vpn client supporting the SOCKS protocol, then you could use this in the middle:

http://http-tunnel.sourceforge.net/

OpenVPN might work as the VPN software.  I haven't had time to try this but my motivation (when I researched it) was the same as your dad.

The other thing you might do is to run ssh-in-a-browser on your own box, or here:

http://www.serfish.com/console/

Comment: A ha, so my dad was wrong. He said that they made the internet in the 60's, and so forwarding ports through the web would be impossible.

Comment: Does the http tunnel give you any security, or is it about as secure as a real open port?

Comment: No, don't even go there.  The tunnel is just to get from behind the firewall to the outside world on ports other than 80.  Actually that's the purpose of SOCKS.  But the traffic on socks will not be encrypted.  The *second* layer, the VPN, does the encryption and sends that traffic ***through*** socks.

Comment: Or ssh, which is what I wanted to user it for.

Comment: Oh, you'd be fine running ssh through the http tunnel.  The real trick is whether or not the firewall/proxy solution recognizes what you're trying to do.

Comment: That might be a thing to try next time I am at my uncles. He pays us to find ways around his firewalls (I wonder if the word "proxy" occurs in the tunnel, or if 443 will encrypt it.) Where I am current just has default filters, and no one has gotten around to opening it, and I don't know the passwords.

Answer (score -2):

Free VPN Type: PPTP VPN US

Server Host: us.websitevpn.com

VPN Username: websitevpn.com

VPN Password: freevpn

---

UK Server Host: uk.websitevpn.com

VPN Username: websitevpn.com

VPN Password: freevpn

---

Via web:

http://anonymouse.org/anonwww.html

http://proxy.org/cgi_proxies.shtml

---

If you need something more advanced you need an openVPN provider and install openVPN in ubuntu:

`sudo apt-get install openvpn bridge-utils`

Comment: I am new to vpn. What would one do with the above information.

Comment: You would install OpenVPN to then be able to contract a VPN service and be able to run the program they will give you to connect to their VPN via OpenVPN that is faster and more secure than PPTP.

Comment: @PyRulez May I suggest Private Internet Access?  It's 7 bucks a month and they have specific installation instructions for Ubuntu on their website: https://www.privateinternetaccess.com

Comment: The http tunnel above seems to meet my needs (or at least claims too.)